# Backing out of Drupal Commons

Tags: 7

We currently have a Drupal Commons website on version 7.50, commons 3.x. Our site is complex and we are no longer using many of the pre-packaged features in the commons distribution. We would like to simplify and modernize our website by "getting out of Commons."

I am wondering if it is possible to back out of Drupal commons without rebuilding from scratch and if it is possible, can it be done cleanly? E.g. Can we get back to Drupal Core and for every commons-specific feature we are using, could we theoretically replace the commons-specific configurations and modules with a Drupal 7 or native features and what are other the other implications?

This is a fairly arbitrary question but any information is appreciated. As I learn to re-frame the question, it will help to answer it. Guidance on asking is also appreciated, thanks!

Update and background info: I prefer Drush, use GIT and have a staging process as well as have set up sandbox copies of our site from back ups to be sure they work. I lack a good understanding about administrating Drupal itself and how Core differs from other profiles but am familiar with migrating Drupal sites and managing the database and codebase.

Comment: You are going to have to be more specific. Like what features are you only using?

Comment: I'm saying, let's pretend that I am not using any commons-specific features and or that I have successfully replaced the features with other modules.

Comment: So assume you're only posting articles?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nice question, but challenging. Basically you want to switch installation profiles (from commons to regular Drupal core). And that yielded some results on Google, including [Profile switcher](https://www.drupal.org/project/profile_switcher) and [This blog page](http://davehall.com.au/blog/dave/2012/09/12/switching-installation-profiles-existing-drupal-sites). They might be of help during the process.

Before blindly installing modules, please read on, make sure you have proper backups (in fact try to verify your backup actually works) you might have to recover multiple times.
From what I understood these methods are usually from upgrading 'standard' Drupal to another profile, but it might work backwards.

I'd start by disabling and **uninstalling** (use the uninstall tab) all modules that come prepacked with your profile distribution. This will likely be the features, but there might be more. Then attempt the switch. See which method works best...

Comment: Thanks for your helpful answer, I have updated my question to add some background information.

Comment: I cannot expand on my answer any further. I have never tried anything similar and it would all be speculation. But I suppose it should be possible. Perhaps someone else knows more. You are free to add your own answer once you have managed it, in fact, please do. Good luck trying ;)